# Como mostrar números pares siguiendo la consigna en Java

Tags: java, bucles, lógica

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me plantean este ejercicio, el primer ciclo lo hago de manera sencilla pero como es posible hacer el segundo si cuando planteo que el resto sea 0 ya es falso al numero inicial ser 5?

```
        while (numeroInicio <= numeroFin && numeroInicio % 2 == 0){
        System.out.println(numeroInicio++);
    }
```

Obviamente esto en consola no me arroja nada.

Comment: Pon también el enunciado _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pones un `if` dentro del `while`

```
while (numeroInicio <= numeroFin) {
  if(numeroInicio % 2 == 0) { // <--- Este if
        System.out.println(numeroInicio);
  }
  numeroInicio++; // sacas la operación ++ fuera del if, así evitas un bucle infinito
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo el enunciado, utilitzando una **sentencia while** (sin ningun if innecesario) sería así:

```
int numeroInicio = 5;
int numeroFin = 14;
int i = numeroInicio + Math.abs(numeroInicio % 2);

while (i <= numeroFin) {
    System.out.println(i);
    i += 2;
}
```

Como ves, **no es necesario comprobar número por número** si es par o impar

Es facil entender donde está el primer numero par partiando de numeroInicio:

```
int i = numeroInicio + Math.abs(numeroInicio % 2);

// si numeroInicio es par, esto sera i = i + 0
// si numeroInicio es impar, sera i = i + 1
// Math.abs es para que sume siempre 1 en valor absoluto. Por que si es un número negativo sumaría `-1`
```

Una vez tenemos localizado el primer numero par, solo hay que ir saltando de 2 en 2 mientras `i` sea mas pequeña o igual que `numeroFin`

**Esto mucho más optimizado** ya que es totalmente innecesario comprobar si es par o impar cada **uno de los numeros** solo hace falta localizar el primer numero par.

Un saludo.